# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while opening file

Tags: python, text-files

studying foundation year ComSci and I'm trying to get a file to open. Here's my code:

```
def main():
    filename = raw_input("Please enter file name ")
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    data = infile.read()
    print data
main()
```

I believe the code is correct but when I try and open a file, for example
C:\Users\Manol\OneDrive\Documents\Uni\Programming\File Processing File

It comes back with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manol\OneDrive\Documents\Uni\Programming\File Processing File\FirstFileProcessingRead.py", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Manol\OneDrive\Documents\Uni\Programming\File Processing File\FirstFileProcessingRead.py", line 3, in main
    infile = open(filename,'r')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Manol\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Uni\\Programming\\File Processing File'
```

Comment: Does the file exist and do you have the rights to read it?

Comment: The file in example doesn't have extension. Please validate that the file path is correct. Also try another file that is maybe in the same directory as python file.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your permissions problem, does open() not need the file extension to function correctly?

```
aa = open("C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd.json","r")
```

will work, whereas

```
aa = open("C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd","r")
```

will return

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd'
```

As a way of testing folder permissions - copy the file to the same area as your .py and try opening it there. If you've still got same problems, then does your account have rights to the file? (right-click >> security)

Comment: Hi there thanks for this I wasn't using the file extension (Plus I made some other stupid mistakes) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See if file is encrypted and put two Backslash ( \\ ) or replace to Forward slash ( / ) and put extension of file

I change a few your code.

```
def main():
    print("Please enter file name:")
    filename = input()
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    data = infile.read()
    print(data)
main()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

While installation when you select **install python only for me** then this issue is likely to happen because python is not granted with the permission to read every location, in your case **One Drive**.

**Solution:**

- Place the file in your python file's root folder i.e inside the folder where you have placed the python file, then this will work.
- You are also not providing extension (.txt). Don't forget to provide it while inputting the data.